# FFMPEG - Nero and Quicktime Format Chapters

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, mp4

Ok, I'm usually really good at finding the answers to my FFMPEG questions myself but I'm a bit stumped.

I've got this file, an MP4, here is part of the MediaInfo:

```
Menu
00:00:00.000                             : CHAPTER01
00:00:23.133                             : CHAPTER02
00:01:31.633                             : CHAPTER03
00:02:05.100                             : CHAPTER04
00:08:04.567                             : CHAPTER05
00:16:03.133                             : CHAPTER06
00:21:45.266                             : CHAPTER07
```

So it has Nero formatted chapters embedded with mp4box. Then when I process this file further with ffmpeg it always comes out like this:

```
Menu #1
ID                                       : 3
Codec ID                                 : text
Duration                                 : 21 min 45 s
Language                                 : English
Bit rate mode                            : CBR
Menu For                                 : 2
00:59:57.994                             : CHAPTER01
01:00:21.127                             : CHAPTER02
01:01:29.627                             : CHAPTER03
01:02:03.094                             : CHAPTER04
01:08:02.561                             : CHAPTER05
01:16:01.127                             : CHAPTER06
01:21:43.260                             : CHAPTER07

Menu #2
00:00:00.000                             : CHAPTER01
00:00:23.133                             : CHAPTER02
00:01:31.633                             : CHAPTER03
00:02:05.100                             : CHAPTER04
00:08:04.567                             : CHAPTER05
00:16:03.133                             : CHAPTER06
00:21:45.266                             : CHAPTER07
```

Now there are 2 chapter streams, I found out that the top is Quicktime formatted and then my original Nero formatted chapters are on the bottom.

Basically I want to only have the original Nero formatted (Menu #2) chapters as anything else makes these chapters not work at all in an Oppo Blu-ray player.

I'm aware of the `-movflags disable_chpl` but that gets rid of the Nero chapter and keeps the Quicktime chapters, I want to do the opposite.

Anyone know of any sort of `-map` or `-map_metadata` or anything that I could do to only have Nero chapters on the output of ffmpeg? For time saving reasons I'd rather not have to embed the chapters with mp4box after ffmpeg, or worse, have to remove the chapters from my files, and then re-embed them after ffmpeg.

Chapter marks are embedded in a batch file with
`mp4box.exe -add %input% -chap %chapters% "%output%\%inputfile%_chapters.mp4"`

Then later on in the workflow encoded with ffmpeg:

`"C:\Users\******\promo _chapters.mp4" -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf yadif -c:
    v libx264 -profile:v high -level 4.0 -preset fast -r 30000/1001 -vsync 1 -bf 1 -
    crf 18 -maxrate 12M -bufsize 12M -movflags +faststart -c:a aac -b:a 192k -ar 48K
     -f mp4 Z:\output\promo.mp4`

Here is the ffmpeg log:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "C:\Users\******\promo _chapters.mp4" -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf yadif -c:
v libx264 -profile:v high -level 4.0 -preset fast -r 30000/1001 -vsync 1 -bf 1 -
crf 18 -maxrate 12M -bufsize 12M -movflags +faststart -c:a aac -b:a 192k -ar 48K
 -f mp4 Z:\output\promo.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.3.1 (GCC) 20190414
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfi
g --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-lib
freetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amr
wb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --
enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-l
ibwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --
enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --en
able-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --en
able-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --e
nable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enab
le-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Users\******\promo _chapters.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isom
    creation_time   : 2019-07-14T20:51:43.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:32.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 145729 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 5.166000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER01
    Chapter #0:1: start 5.166000, end 10.233000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER02
    Chapter #0:2: start 10.233000, end 14.867000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER03
    Chapter #0:3: start 14.867000, end 21.367000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER04
    Chapter #0:4: start 21.367000, end 24.400000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER05
    Chapter #0:5: start 24.400000, end 29.333000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER06
    Chapter #0:6: start 29.333000, end 32.032032
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER07
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: dnxhd (DNXHD) (AVdn / 0x6E645641), yuv422p(tv, bt70
9/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080, 145344 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.97 fps, 29.97 t
br, 29970 tbn, 29970 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-04-26T19:59:22.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Apple Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Avid DNxHD Codec
      timecode        : 00:59:58;00
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, stereo, s3
2 (24 bit), 2304 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-04-26T19:59:22.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Apple Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-04-26T19:59:34.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Time Code Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:59:58;00
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (dnxhd (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s24le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 00000000006c0140] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 00000000006c0140] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 00000000006c0140] profile Progressive High, level 4.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 00000000006c0140] 264 - core 157 r2970 5493be8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC cod
ec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 r
ef=2 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=6 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed
_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pski
p=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=34 lookahead_threads=5 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 dec
imate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=1 b_pyramid=0 b
_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=1 keyint=250 keyint_min=
25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=30 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=18.0 qcomp=0.
60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=12000 vbv_bufsize=12000 crf_max=0.0 nal
_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'Z:\output\promo.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isom
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 5.166000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER01
    Chapter #0:1: start 5.166000, end 10.233000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER02
    Chapter #0:2: start 10.233000, end 14.867000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER03
    Chapter #0:3: start 14.867000, end 21.367000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER04
    Chapter #0:4: start 21.367000, end 24.400000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER05
    Chapter #0:5: start 24.400000, end 29.333000
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER06
    Chapter #0:6: start 29.333000, end 32.032032
    Metadata:
      title           : CHAPTER07
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1
080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 0.03 fps, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-04-26T19:59:22.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Apple Video Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:59:58;00
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 12000000/0/0 buffer size: 12000000 vbv_delay: -1

    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, flt
p (24 bit), 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-04-26T19:59:22.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Apple Sound Media Handler
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 aac
frame=   14 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.93 bitrate=   1.8kbits/s
frame=   43 fps= 43 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.00 bitrate=   0.8kbits/s
frame=   74 fps= 49 q=24.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.28 bitrate=   0.5kbits/
frame=  124 fps= 62 q=24.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:04.69 bitrate=   0.4kbits/
frame=  166 fps= 66 q=24.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:06.08 bitrate=2069.8kbits/
frame=  204 fps= 67 q=24.0 size=    3840kB time=00:00:07.48 bitrate=4201.3kbits/
frame=  242 fps= 69 q=26.0 size=    5632kB time=00:00:08.89 bitrate=5186.5kbits/
frame=  284 fps= 70 q=25.0 size=    7424kB time=00:00:10.28 bitrate=5914.7kbits/
frame=  325 fps= 72 q=24.0 size=    9472kB time=00:00:11.69 bitrate=6637.5kbits/
frame=  367 fps= 73 q=26.0 size=   11264kB time=00:00:13.09 bitrate=7044.7kbits/
frame=  407 fps= 73 q=28.0 size=   13056kB time=00:00:14.14 bitrate=7562.0kbits/
frame=  448 fps= 74 q=29.0 size=   15360kB time=00:00:15.44 bitrate=8146.9kbits/
frame=  491 fps= 75 q=26.0 size=   17664kB time=00:00:16.91 bitrate=8553.7kbits/
frame=  532 fps= 75 q=24.0 size=   19712kB time=00:00:18.30 bitrate=8822.2kbits/
frame=  574 fps= 76 q=24.0 size=   21504kB time=00:00:19.62 bitrate=8975.7kbits/
frame=  615 fps= 76 q=24.0 size=   23040kB time=00:00:21.03 bitrate=8973.1kbits/
frame=  656 fps= 76 q=27.0 size=   25088kB time=00:00:22.44 bitrate=9157.7kbits/
frame=  695 fps= 76 q=24.0 size=   27136kB time=00:00:23.82 bitrate=9328.8kbits/
frame=  736 fps= 77 q=25.0 size=   29184kB time=00:00:25.23 bitrate=9473.1kbits/
frame=  776 fps= 77 q=24.0 size=   30976kB time=00:00:26.64 bitrate=9523.5kbits/
frame=  813 fps= 77 q=24.0 size=   33024kB time=00:00:27.86 bitrate=9710.0kbits/
frame=  854 fps= 77 q=24.0 size=   34816kB time=00:00:28.97 bitrate=9844.9kbits/
frame=  896 fps= 77 q=24.0 size=   36352kB time=00:00:30.40 bitrate=9796.0kbits/
frame=  936 fps= 77 q=24.0 size=   37632kB time=00:00:31.78 bitrate=9698.5kbits/
[mp4 @ 000000000282e7c0] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the begin
ning of the file
frame=  960 fps= 62 q=-1.0 Lsize=   39818kB time=00:00:32.04 bitrate=10179.8kbit
s/s speed=2.07x
video:39018kB audio:763kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxi
ng overhead: 0.093123%
[libx264 @ 00000000006c0140] frame I:11    Avg QP:16.42  size:119041
[libx264 @ 00000000006c0140] frame P:486   Avg QP:20.49  size: 62131
[libx264 @ 00000000006c0140] frame B:463   Avg QP:22.45  size: 18246
[libx264 @ 00000000006c0140] consecutive B-frames:  3.5% 96.5%
[libx264 @ 00000000006c0140] mb I  I16..4: 26.0% 64.5%  9.5%
[libx264 @ 00000000006c0140] mb P  I16..4:  4.2% 16.2%  1.6%  P16..4: 37.2% 16.7
%  8.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:16.0%
[libx264 @ 00000000006c0140] mb B  I16..4:  2.7%  7.4%  0.3%  B16..8: 17.8%  5.6
%  0.4%  direct:20.5%  skip:45.4%  L0:40.2% L1:47.0% BI:12.8%
[libx264 @ 00000000006c0140] 8x8 transform intra:72.3% inter:69.6%
[libx264 @ 00000000006c0140] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 54.4% 80.0% 47.2% inter: 2
4.8% 38.9% 7.1%
[libx264 @ 00000000006c0140] i16 v,h,dc,p: 34% 26% 12% 28%
[libx264 @ 00000000006c0140] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 24% 19% 25%  4%  5%
 6%  5%  6%  5%
[libx264 @ 00000000006c0140] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 24% 22% 10%  5%  9%
 8%  9%  6%  7%
[libx264 @ 00000000006c0140] i8c dc,h,v,p: 51% 21% 20%  8%
[libx264 @ 00000000006c0140] Weighted P-Frames: Y:6.8% UV:2.5%
[libx264 @ 00000000006c0140] ref P L0: 79.5% 20.5%
[libx264 @ 00000000006c0140] kb/s:9978.35
[aac @ 00000000006c69c0] Qavg: 3776.600
```

Comment: Share full command and log.

Comment: @Gyan Sorry I didn't include that before, the question is updated now.